# Uploading JSON to Bigquery unspecific error

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am just getting started with the python BigQuery API (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery) after briefly trying out (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq) and realizing that the pandas-gbq does not support RECORD type, i.e. no nested fields.

Now I am trying to upload nested data to BigQuery. I managed to create the table with the respective Schema, however I am struggling with the upload of the json data.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import Dataset
from google.cloud.bigquery import LoadJobConfig
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField

SCHEMA = [
    SchemaField('full_name', 'STRING', mode='required'),
    SchemaField('age', 'INTEGER', mode='required'),
    SchemaField('address', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED', fields=(
        SchemaField('test', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        SchemaField('second','STRING', mode='NULLABLE')
    ))
]

table_ref = client.dataset('TestApartments').table('Test2')

table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=SCHEMA)
table = client.create_table(table)
```

When trying to upload a very simple JSON to bigquery I get a rather ambiguous error

> 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered
>   too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the
>   error stream for more details.

Beside the fact that it makes me kinda sad that its giving up on me :), obviously that error description does not really help ...
Please find below how I try to upload the JSON and the sampledata.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

with open('testjson.json', 'rb') as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file,
        table_ref,
        location='US',  # Must match the destination dataset location.
        job_config=job_config)  # API request

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
    job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

This is my JSON object

> "[{'full_name':'test','age':2,'address':[{'test':'hi','second':'hi2'}]}]"

A JSON example would be wonderful as this seems the only way to upload nested data if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been reproducing your scenario using your same code and the JSON content you shared, and I suspect the issue is only that you are defining the JSON content between quotation marks (`"` or `'`), while it should not have that format.

The correct format is the one that @ElliottBrossard already shared with you in his answer:

```
{'full_name':'test', 'age':2, 'address': [{'test':'hi', 'second':'hi2'}]}
```

If I run your code using that content in the `testjson.json` file, I get the response `Loaded 1 rows into MY_DATASET:MY_TABLE` and the content gets loaded in the table. If, otherwise, I use the format below (which you are using according to your question and the comments in the other answer), I get the result `google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details`.

```
"{'full_name':'test','age':2,'address':[{'test':'hi','second':'hi2'}]}"
```

Additionally, you can go to the Jobs page in the BigQuery UI (following the link *https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/YOUR_PROJECT_ID*), and there you will find more information about the failed Load job. As an example, when I run your code with the wrong JSON format, this is what I get:

[image]

As you will see, here the error message is more relevant:

```
error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Value encountered without start of object
```

It indicates that the it could not find any valid start of a JSON object (i.e. a bracket `{` at the very beginning of the object).

***TL;DR:*** remove the quotation marks in your JSON object and the load job should be fine.

Comment: You are a genius! Thx @dsesto, much appreciated :D

Comment: I am glad I could help and clarify the issue! Next time make sure to follow all the steps in the previous answers, as @ElliottBrossard had already posted the right JSON format in his answer ;)

Comment: He did indeed, I copied the part from the echo and focused on the brackets. Anyway, thx for helping. Any idea, why my failed jobs though the python API don't show up in the list?

Comment: In which list? Are they not available through [the jobs page](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs)?

Comment: Nope, they are not (none of the python jobs show up there). They do show up when running bq ls -j --all, but produce an error when explicitly querying for them with bq show -j <job_id> [job_id is obtained from bq ls -j --all]

Answer (score 1):

I think your JSON content should be:

```
{'full_name':'test','age':2,'address':[{'test':'hi','second':'hi2'}]}
```

(No brackets.) As an example using the command-line client:

```
$ echo "{'full_name':'test','age':2,'address':[{'test':'hi','second':'hi2'}]}" \
    > example.json
$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
    "CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.JsonExample (full_name STRING NOT NULL, age INT64 NOT NULL, address ARRAY<STRUCT<test STRING, second STRING>>);"
$ bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
    tmp_elliottb.JsonExample example.json
$ bq head tmp_elliottb.JsonExample
+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+
| full_name | age |            address             |
+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+
| test      |   2 | [{"test":"hi","second":"hi2"}] |
+-----------+-----+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: thx for the response, I tried what you suggested and keep stumbling over the same error. I tried various permutations of quotes (i.e. " and ') to no avail. Really weird ...

Comment: You removed the brackets? And put each JSON object on a separate line?

Comment: Did indeed, for now this really is only the one test JSON Object as I want to get a prototype working before moving to real data. I tried:
"{'full_name':'test','age':2,'address':[{'test':'hi','second':'hi2'}]}" as well as '{"full_name":"test","age":2,"address":[{"test":"hi","second":"hi2"}]}' and even added a \n for good measure '{"full_name":"test","age":2,"address":[{"test":"hi","second":"hi2"}]}\n' and tried this one as well.

Comment: Check the job information to see what the actual error is...if you have the job ID, use the `bq` command-line line and run `bq show -j <job_id>`. You can also use `bq ls -j` to list recent jobs. There is a way to see the loading errors from the Python client, too, but I don't know where to look off the top of my head.

Comment: installed the SDK and ran ** bq ls -j ** . I don't get any results though. when running bq ls I see the dataset I would expect to see in the project.

Comment: I tried running a couple of uploads from the command line, which work fine. I also see the jobs ran from the command line with bq ls -j. However the jobs from the python api don't show up.

Comment: Try the `--all` option. See [this tip](https://googlecloud.tips/tips/006-list-all-bigquery-jobs-for-all-users/), for example.

Comment: Thx Elliott, I did just that and managed to obtain the list of jobs. I noticed that the jobs I ran through the commandline start with a bqjob_ and results can be obtained through bq show, for the other jobs that is not the case and the following error is produced upon the bq show command BigQuery error in show operation: Not found: Job <my job id here>

Comment: Comming back to this because its been a tremendous help for quite some time, can I somehow get an extended list of bq ls -j --all? Or is it possible to only see the FAILURE jobs?

Comment: You can pass the `-n` option to see more jobs, e.g. `bq ls -j --all -n 1000` to see 1000 jobs. You can also do something like `bq ls -j --all -n 1000 | grep FAILURE` to see the failed ones.